# Trying to filter rows by intervals and plotting number of rows obtained

Tags: r, ggplot2, tibble

Consider the column "disp" in mtcars. I am trying to divide disp into intervals so that I can count the number of observations in each interval. After doing this I want to plot the results as a ggplot geom_line

This is what I have tried:

```
library (tidyverse)
library (ggplot2)

a1 <- mtcars %>% arrange(desc(disp)) %>%
  mutate(counts = cut_interval(disp, length = 5)) %>% group_by(counts) %>% mutate(nn = n())

a2 <- a1 %>% select(counts,nn) %>% unique()

ggplot(a2, aes(counts, nn)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, size = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()
```

I get the intervals I need in a2. i can use it to plot a scatterplot but I can see that there is no proper scale. Is there any way to use these intervals to get a continuous scale and draw a lineplot of counts vs nn?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put in the required libraries which are : 

library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

Comment: You may edit your question using the `edit` link below.

Comment: You can avoid the second pipe with `summarise(nn = n())` instead of `mutate` after `group_by`.

Comment: How do you propose to have a continuous scale? You have binned the data, the data points now fall into *categories*, they no longer are *numbers*.

Comment: The objective of doing this was to plot how many observations I get after increasing the filters in intervals of 5. I understand that they are no longer numbers. Maybe I can grep the interval and extract the first number but that seems crude.

Answer (score 0):

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = disp)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) + theme_bw()
```

Thanks so much [Rui Barradas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8245406/rui-barradas)! I just needed a count plot so no need of doing extra stuff.